# Powershell INI editing

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to changing some values in an INI file. Unfortunately, I have keys in 2 different sections which share an identical name but need different values. My code uses the `Get-IniContent` function from [`PsIni`](https://github.com/lipkau/PsIni).

Example INI file:

```ini
[PosScreen]
BitmapFile=C:\Temp\Random.bmp
Bitmap=1

[ControlScreen]
BitmapFile=C:\Temp\Random.bmp
Bitmap=1
```

I need to change the above to the following:

```ini
[PosScreen]
BitmapFile=C:\Temp\FileC.bmp
Bitmap=1

[ControlScreen]
BitmapFile=C:\Temp\FileD.bmp
Bitmap=1
```

The PowerShell code I am using seems to work, but it changes every value to "File D". It is obviously parsing everything twice, and the name is the same for each section.

```powershell
$NewFileC = "C:\Temp\FileC.bmp"
$NewFileD = "C:\Temp\FileD.bmp"
$POSIniContent = Get-IniContent "C:\scripts\Update-EnablerImage\WINSUITE.INI"
$BOIniContent = Get-IniContent "C:\scripts\Update-EnablerImage\WINSUITE.INI"

If ($POSIniContent["PosScreen"]["BitmapFile"] -ne $NewFileC) {
  Get-Content "C:\scripts\Update-EnablerImage\WINSUITE.INI" |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "BitmapFile=.+" , "BitmapFile=$NewFileC" } |
    Set-Content "C:\scripts\Update-EnablerImage\WINSUITE.INI"
}

If ($BOIniContent["ControlScreen"]["BitmapFile"] -ne $NewFileD) {
  Get-Content "C:\scripts\Update-EnablerImage\WINSUITE.INI" |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "BitmapFile=.+" , "BitmapFile=$NewFileD" } |
    Set-Content "C:\scripts\Update-EnablerImage\WINSUITE.INI"
}
```

My struggle is how to change each one independently. I'm a bit of a scripting newbie, so calling out for some help. Tried using Conditional Logic (`ForEach $line in $INIFile`, for example), but no luck with that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. You can use `Get-IniContent` and `Out-IniFile` as follows:

```
$ini = Get-IniContent c:\temp\ini.ini 
$ini["posscreen"]["BitmapFile"] = "C:\Temp\FileC.bmp"  
$ini | Out-IniFile -FilePath c:\temp\ini2.ini
```

Note that if you want to overwrite the original file, you must add `-Force` to the `Out-IniFile` call.

Comment: Get-IniContent is not [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338755/function-get-inicontent-is-not-recognized-ini-file-support-inpowershell) for more info

Comment: After editing the ini file the program (c#) that would read it afterwards was not able to read the first section of the file. The issue was with the encondig, I had to set it to ascii; `$ini | Out-IniFile -FilePath $iniPath -Encoding ascii `