# Function Get-IniContent is not recognized - INI file support inPowerShell

Tags: powershell, ini

I want to edit the value of INI file. I use this script but It gives me error.

```
Get-IniContent : The term 'Get-IniContent' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

The contents of my INI file at `c:\Users\file.ini`:

```
[XXX]
AB=23
BC=34
```

The contents of the script for reading and updating it:

```
# Read the content of an *.ini file into a (nested) hashtable.
$ini = Get-IniContent "C:\Users\file.ini"

# Update the 'AB' entry in section [XXX] in-memory.
$ini["XXX"]["AB"] = "12"  

# Write the updated content back to the *.ini file.
$ini | Out-IniFile -FilePath "C:\Users\file.ini -Force"
```

Comment: That's because `Get-IniContent` is not a standard cmdlet included in a vanilla PowerShell installation. (Neither is `Out-IniFile`.) There are various scripts online offering such cmdlets, but you'll have to import them in your session first to get them. Try [`Import-Module PsIni`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni) -- you may need to install it first, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JeroenMostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

**PowerShell, as of v7.2.x, has *no* built-in cmdlets for processing INI files (`*.ini`)**, though introducing such cmdlets is being discussed [in GitHub issue #9035](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9035).

`Get-IniContent` and `Out-IniFile` are advanced functions (cmdlet-like functions) that come with the **[third-party `PSIni` module](https://github.com/lipkau/PsIni)**, [available from the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/).

In PowerShell v5 or higher, which comes with the `PowerShellGet` module<sup>[1]</sup>, **installation** is as easy as:

```bash
Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser PsIni
```

<sup>If you omit `-Scope CurrentUser`, you'll install the module for *all* users, but doing so requires running with administrative privileges.</sup>

With `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` at its default (unset), this module is then loaded *automatically, on demand* into a session that tries to call one of the module's commands, such as `Get-IniContent`.

Here's a complete, self-contained example that exercises the core functionality of the `PsIni` module:

- installs the module on demand
- creates a sample `*.ini` file from scratch with `Out-IniFile`, from a nested ordered hashtable.
- reads the file from disk with `Get-IniContent` into a (new) nested ordered hashtable
- modifies and removes entries
- writes the modified hashtable back to the file with `Out-IniFile`

Note: The assumptions are that `Install-Module` is available, i.e., that the `PowerShellGet` module is installed, and that the running machine is online and permitted to download packages from https://www.powershellgallery.com/.

```bash
# Import the PsIni module.
# If necessary, install it first, for the current user.
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' # Abort, if something unexpectedly goes wrong.
try {
  Import-Module PsIni
} catch {
  Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser PsIni
  Import-Module PsIni
}

# Create an ordered hashtable that is the in-memory representation of the
# sample *.ini file from the question, with a second section added.
$iniFileContent = [ordered] @{
  # 'XXX' is the section name.
  # The nested hashtable contains that section's entries.
  XXX = [ordered] @{  
    # IMPORTANT: 
    #  * The PsIni module only supports STRING values.
    #  * While you can assign values of different types in-memory, they are
    #    CONVERTED TO STRINGS with .ToString() and READ AS STRINGS later
    #    by Get-IniContent.
    #  * In v3+, PSIni now supports values in *.ini files that have 
    #    embedded quoting - e.g., `AB = "23"` as a raw line - which is
    #    (sensibly) *stripped* on reading the values.
    AB = '23'
    BC = '34'
  }
  # Create a 2nd section, named 'YYY', with entries 'yin' and 'yang'
  YYY = [ordered] @{
    yin = 'foo'
    yang = 'none'
  }
}

# Use Out-IniFile to create file 'file.ini' in the current dir.
# * Default encoding is UTF-8 (with BOM in Windows PowerShell, without BOM
#   in PowerShell Core)
# * Use -Encoding to override, but note that
#   Get-IniContent has no matching -Encoding parameter, so the encoding you use
#   must be detectable by PowerShell in the absence of explicit information.
# * CAVEAT: -Force is only needed if an existing file must be overwritten.
#           I'm using it here so you can run the sample code repeatedly without
#           failure, but in general you should only use it if you want to
#           blindly replace an existing file - such as after having modified
#           the in-memory representation of an *.ini file and wanting to
#           write the modifications back to disk - see below.
$iniFileContent | Out-IniFile -Force file.ini

# Read the file back into a (new) ordered hashtable 
$iniFileContent = Get-IniContent file.ini

# Modify the value of the [XXX] section's 'AB' entry.
$iniFileContent.XXX.AB = '12'

# Use the alternative *indexing syntax* (which is equivalent in most cases)
# to also modify the [YYY] section's 'yin' entry.
$iniFileContent['YYY']['yin'] = 'bar'

# Remove the 'yang' value from section [YYY]:
$iniFileContent.YYY.Remove('yang')

# Save the modified content back to the original file.
# Note that -Force is now *required* to signal the explicit intent to
# replace the existing file.
$iniFileContent | Out-IniFile -Force file.ini

# Double-check that modifying the values succeeded.
(Get-IniContent file.ini).XXX.AB # should output '12'
(Get-IniContent file.ini).YYY.yin # should output 'bar'

# Print the updated content of the INI file, which
# shows the updated values and the removal of 'yang' from [YYY].
"--- Contents of file.ini:"
Get-Content file.ini
```

Running the above should succeed and output the following, demonstrating that the `*.ini` file was successfully created, read back into memory, modified, and saved back to disk:

```bash
12
bar
--- Contents of file.ini:
[XXX]
AB=12
BC=34
[YYY]
yin=bar
```

---

<sup>[1] You can install `PowerShellGet` on demand for PowerShell versions 3 and 4 - see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51451</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Since I am new to powershell when I read this post I first thought I had to use the cmdlets to read and write Ini-Files.
However, it is not necessary.

```
$ini= [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\temp\test.ini")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("c:\temp\test2.ini", $ini)
```

This works as well...just wanted to share :)