# PowerShell - check .ini file, log issues

Tags: powershell, ini

Having trouble with two VNC servers switching off MS Logon Groups being forced. I'm troubleshooting the issue, and one thing I want to do is monitor the config .ini file. I'm relatively new to PowerShell and can't quite get this to work.

Basically, I want the script to check the contents of the configuration file (ultravnc.ini) and see if "MSLogonRequired=1" is a string in that file. If not, I want to append the date to a log file. Eventually I'll do some more with this, but this is my basic need. It's not currently working.

```
# Variables 
$outputFile = "vncMSLogonErrors.txt" 
$vncConfig = "C:\Program Files (x86)\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\ultravnc.ini"
$checkString = "MSLogonRequired=1"


# Get VNC Config File, check for MS Logon setting, write date to file if missing
Get-Content $vncConfig
If (-not $checkString)
   {Add-Content $outputFile -Value $(Get-Date)}
```

Comment: use `Get-Content` to load the file, iterate thru it, if the check string is not found then add it.

Comment: `if((Get-Content $vncConfig -raw) -notmatch $checkString){Set-content $outputFile -Value $(Get-Date) -Append}`

Answer (score 1):

```
# Variables 
$outputFile = "vncMSLogonErrors.txt" 
$vncConfig = "C:\Program Files (x86)\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\ultravnc.ini"
$checkString = "MSLogonRequired=1"

if ((get-content $vncconfig) -notcontains $checkString)) { Add-Content $outputFile -Value $(Get-Date) }
```

Comment: See `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators` cite: `Description: Containment operator. Tells whether a collection of reference values includes a single test value. Always eturns a Boolean value. Returns TRUE only when the test value exactly matches at least one of the reference values.`

Comment: @LotPings: If you're looking for a line that exactly matches `MSLogonRequired=1` (except for case variations), this approach works fine.

Comment: @mklement0 Agreed, the emphasis lying on exactly, just a trailing space wouldn't match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

[Shamus Berube's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55750694/45375) is conceptually simple and works well, if you can assume:

- that the line of interest is exactly `MSLogonRequired=1`, with no variations in whitespace.
- that if the INI file is subdivided into multiple sections (e.g, `[admin]`), that the key name `MSLogonRequired` is unique among the sections, to prevent false positives.

It is therefore **generally preferable to use a dedicated INI-file-parsing command**; unfortunately:

- **PowerShell doesn't come with one**, though [adding one is being debated](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9035)
- in the meantime you can **use the popular `PsIni` third-party module** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55341293/45375) for how to install it and for background information):

Using the `PsIni` module's `Get-IniContent` function:

Note: Based on the [UltraVNC INI-file documentation](http://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-server/69-ultravncini.html), the code assumes that the `MSLogonRequired` entry is inside the `[admin]` section of the INI file.

```
# Variables 
$outputFile = "vncMSLogonErrors.txt" 
$vncConfig = "C:\Program Files (x86)\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\ultravnc.ini"

# Check the VNC Config File to see if the [admin] section's 'MSLogonRequired'
# entry, if present, has value '1'.
if ((Get-IniContent $vncConfig).admin.MSLogonRequired -ne '1') {
   Add-Content $outputFile -Value (Get-Date) 
}
```