# Adding a new stanza between existing stanzas with Powershell

Tags: powershell

After doing numerous online searches I have yet to find a way to do this.  There are really two parts to my question:

1. How do you add a new stanza between two existing ones?

   If I have the following stanzas in an existing file:

   ```
   [Section 1]
   Host=A
   IP=10.10.10.1

   [Section 2]
   Host=B
   IP=10.10.10.2
   ```

   How can I use Powershell to add:

   ```
   [Section 3]
   Host=C
   IP=10.10.10.3
   ```

   between Section 1 and Section 2 to achieve:

   ```
   [Section 1]
   Host=A
   IP=10.10.10.1

   [Section 3]
   Host=C
   IP=10.10.10.3

   [Section 2]
   Host=B
   IP=10.10.10.2
   ```
2. How do I add a new stanza after the last comment line of an existing file?

   For example if I have:

   ```
   #
   # Last change 1/1/2021
   #

   [Profile sql]
   Profile=HR
   ```

   How would I add:

   ```
   [Profile postgres]
   Profile=Exec
   ```

   to achieve:

   ```
   #
   # Last change 1/1/2021
   #

   [Profile postgres]
   Profile=Exec

   [Profile sql]
   Profile=HR
   ```

   in Powershell?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: (_Having said the above, your file looks like an old Windows INI file. As such, you might find [Dr Scripto's column of 20 Aug 2011](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file/) to be of interest._)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55341293/45375